# Grothendieck quote: Why is Galois theory a "geometrical vision"?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, galois-theory

In *Récoltes et semailles*, Grothendieck writes

> observe that the concept of the group (notably of symmetries) appeared only in the last century (introduced by Évariste Galois), in a context that was considered to have nothing to do with Geometry. Even in our own time it is true that there are lots of algebraists who still haven't understood that Galois Theory is primarily, in essence, a geometrical vision, which was able to renew our understanding of so-called "arithmetical" phenomenon.

I don't understand why Galois theory (which is a theory that connects field theory and group theory) is a "geometrical vision". Isn't it more an algebraic theory in the sense that it connects two different kind of algebraic structures (fields and groups)?

Comment: The theory of fundamental groups and universal covering spaces mirrors Galois theory in a geometric environment. Using algebraic geometry and etale cohomology these ideas become generalized. Essentially, we think of automorphisms of a covering space which fix the base space.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But I guess "Galois theory" here just means "elementary" Galois theory.

Comment: In that case, you can think of field extensions as vector space, and the Galois group as the automorphisms of said vector spaces which also respect the field structure.